# Default Backcolor on tabControl is different on new machine

Tags: c#, winforms, themes, tabcontrol

I am running the same code on a new machine with same VS and .net version (pretty much!)

On old machine backcolor was white or transparent, but it is grey on new machine.

Is there a simple way of changing this color? Either changing the entire default theme(?), or if necessary changing specific tabControls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the drawitem event of the tab control.

You can then set the backcolor of each tab as it renders.

Comment: But on my old machine it had a different "theme" - can't I just select similar?